# Django ForeignKey in Modelform validation error

Tags: python, django, validation, modelform

I'm using a Modelform which contains a ForeignKey. The ForeignKey-Field is populated in the template with ajax, so I only get a string in the view (a name in this case). The POST-Data looks like this:

```
{'text': 'test', 'author': 'firstname lastname'}
```

What I do with this:

```
postdata = request.POST.copy()
postdata['author'] = Author.objects.get(slug=slugify(postdata['author']))

form = MyModelForm(postdata)
if form.is_valid():
    ...
```

But then I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "u'firstname lastname'": "Quote.author" must be a "Author" instance.
```

If I do the same in a python-shell I get the same error, but if I do `form.is_valid()` a second time, then everything is fine (the form validates). WHAT IS GOING ON?

Thanks in advance and all the best,
Jacques

Comment: Could it be that the author field received by the form is still a unicode (not an 'Author' object)? Can you insert a pdb before the if statement and print the content of postdata? `import pdb` `pdb.set_trace()`

Comment: The content of postdata is:
<QueryDict: {u'text': [u'test'], u'author': [<Author: Firstname Lastname>], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken':[u'824748c007d8e8328932f6b651bf4fea']}>

So it's definitely a Author object.